# How to exclude the bracketed characters in a Python f-string using regex?

Tags: python, regex, f-string

Recently, I have been creating an editor in Python 3.7.6 (using tkinter), I created the following syntax for highlighting single, double and triple quotes but I want to exclude all the characters inside a curly bracket of an f-string, I tried using `[^\{(.*)\}]` as a negated set, but then realized it wouldn't work. I tried searching on the internet but all those didn't fit in with my regex.

This is the regex part of the code :

```py
def regex_groups(self, name, alternates):
    return "(?P<%s>" % name + "|".join(alternates) + ")"

stringprefix = r"(\bB|b|br|Br|bR|BR|rb|rB|Rb|RB|r|u|R|U|f|F|fr|Fr|fR|FR|rf|rF|Rf|RF)?"
sqstring = stringprefix + r"'[^'\\\n]*(\\.[^'\\\n]*)*'?"
dqstring = stringprefix + r'"[^"\\\n]*(\\.[^"\\\n]*)*"?'
sqqqstring = stringprefix + r"'''[^'\\]*((\\.|'(?!''))[^'\\]*)*(''')?"
dqqqstring = stringprefix + r'"""[^"\\]*((\\.|"(?!""))[^"\\]*)*(""")?'
string = self.regex_groups("STRING", [sqqqstring, dqqqstring, sqstring, dqstring])
```

What I tried was to break `stringprefix` into two strings `r"(f|F|fr|Fr|fR|FR|rf|rF|Rf|RF)?"` and `r"(B|b|br|Br|bR|BR|rb|rB|Rb|RB|r|u|R|U)?"` and then using both with `sqstring, dqstring, sq3string and dq3string` separately, but it wasn't successful.

Here is one of the part of the regex testing :
[image]

Please help me !

Any help is appreciated ! :)

Comment: What do you expect for the third string with the curly's?

Comment: Pairs of opening/closing characters are not regular. You cannot accurately match them using regular expressions.

Comment: My expectations are that it should highlight `f'This is an {` , leave the ones in between (in this case `f_string` and then `}'`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi When I try regex for excluding text from, in between, any kind of braces without quotes it works but with quotes it doesn't

Comment: What result do you expect for ``f"This is an {{plain string}}"`` and ``f"This is a set: { {1, 2, 3}}"``?

Comment: For this the furthermost and the last curly bracket should be included in the string and the `{plain string}` and `{1, 2, 3}` should be excluded from regex matching.

Comment: Could there be any relation for this with delimiters ?? IDK much because I'm new to these regexes and this is the first complex one I have ever created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if regexes are the way to go here. You could just use the `tokenize` module, which is part of the standard library, to parse and tokenize your Python source code. Depending on each token's type, you choose a different color. For example:

```
import tokenize
from io import BytesIO

src = """
def foo(bar):
    print(bar, "hi there")
"""

tokens = tokenize.tokenize(BytesIO(src.encode("utf-8")).readline)

openers = ("class", "def", "for", "while", "if", "try", "except")

for token in tokens:
    color = ""
    line = token.start[0]
    start = token.start[1]
    end = token.end[1]
    if token.exact_type == tokenize.NAME and token.string in openers:
        color = "orange"
    elif token.exact_type == tokenize.NAME:
        color = "blue"
    elif token.exact_type == tokenize.STRING:
        color = "green"

    if color:
        print(f"token '{token.string}' (line: {line}, col: {start} - {end}) should be {color}")
```

Output:

```
token 'def' (line: 2, col: 0 - 3) should be orange
token 'foo' (line: 2, col: 4 - 7) should be blue
token 'bar' (line: 2, col: 8 - 11) should be blue
token 'print' (line: 3, col: 4 - 9) should be blue
token 'bar' (line: 3, col: 10 - 13) should be blue
token '"hi there"' (line: 3, col: 15 - 25) should be green
>>>
```

A lookup table (dictionary) to map token types to colors would be more appropriate than a big chunk of if-statements, but you get the idea.

Comment: You are right, but the editor has already been made and it works just like the built-in IDLE but with more features (like auto-completion of brackets, auto-completion of statements like `if __name__ == '__main__'` , `def __init__(self):`, etc, etc). So maybe rewriting the whole thing might not be a good idea for this one but still thanks for the answer. I can use it in another editor (like a second version of the editor I made or something like that). But for now my only hope for the f-string feature is regex (IF POSSIBLE).